# awk working with intervals

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have this file

```
goodtime 20:30 21:40
badtime 19:52 24:00
```

and when I enter for example `21:00` and `21:15` I should get `goodtime`

So here's my script

```
#!/bin/sh

last > duom.txt

grep -F 'stud.if.ktu.lt' duom.txt > ktu.txt

echo "Nurodykite laiko intervala "
read h
read min
read h2
read min2

awk '{if ($2 ~ /$h.$m/ && $3 ~ /$h2.$min2/) print $1}' data.txt
```

But I don't get any results.

Comment: Why should you get "goodtime" with "21:00" and "21:15"? Why not "badtime"? Both of those times seem to be included in the good and bad intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this:

```
awk '{if ($2 ~ /$h.$m/ && $3 ~ /$h2.$min2/) print $1}' data.txt
```

Is that you're trying to use shell variables in a single quoted string. You need to pass the shell variables into awk with its `-v` option:

```
awk -v patt1="$h.$min" -v patt2="$h2.$min2" '
    $2 ~ patt1 && $3 ~ patt2 {print $1}
' data.txt
```

But, given your sample input, this will not match anything.

Until your requirements are clarified, I can't help with the logic.